# Are Skewness and Kurtosis Sufficient Statistics?

Tags: normal-distribution, skewness, kurtosis, sufficient-statistics

I would like to prove that Skewness and Kurtosis are sufficient statistics for gaussian distribution.

Later on I will try to prove on loglogistic distribution.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You are going to fail --- you cannot prove what is not true

Comment: Can you give some detail? What is the reason?

Comment: You obtain absolutely no information about the location of a Gaussian from the skewness or kurtosis.  Proof: they are the same for a Normal$(\mu,\sigma)$ and Normal$(\mu^\prime,\sigma)$ distribution, for any $\mu$ or $\mu^\prime$. Indeed, skewness is worthless, because it's always zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's right. How can I prove these two are sufficient statistic  on Loglogistic distribution? Any idea?

Comment: Why would you think they are? What theorems exist that relate to sufficiency?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to fail --- you cannot prove what is not true!

More details:  You obtain absolutely no information about the location of a Gaussian from the skewness or kurtosis. Proof: they are the same for a $\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$ and $\text{Normal}(\mu′,\sigma)$ distribution, for any μ or μ′. Indeed, skewness is worthless, because it's always zero. (stated in comments by whuber).

As for the same question for loglogistic distribution, you would have to tell us *why* you expect skewness and kurtosis to be sufficient in that case (it is not).

Comment: This answer is presently flawed.  *Sample* skewness is not always zero.  In fact, it is non-zero with probability one (though it has a distribution that does not depend on $\mu$).